# Having issues in FlatList component

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

What happpening here is that in my android studio i can see the first option which is by the name of FIFA 20 but not others and there is no styles generted either for others options

1. This is the code and style

   const ProductCard = (props) => {
   const { name, price, image, countInStock } = props;

   ```
      return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <Image 
              style={styles.image}
              resizeMode="contain"
              source={{url: image ? image : ''}}
              />
              <View style={styles.card}/>
              <Text style={styles.title}>
              {name.length > 15 ? name.substring(0, 15 - 3)
                      + '...' : name
                  }
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.price}>${price}</Text>

              { countInStock > 0 ? (
                  <View style = {{marginBottom: 60}}>
                      <Button title={'Add'} color={'green'} />
                  </View>   
              ):<Text style={{marginTop: 20 }}>Currently Unavialable</Text> }
          </View>
      )
   ```

   }

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
   width: width / 2 - 20,
   height: width / 1.7,
   padding: 10,
   borderRadius: 10,
   marginTop: 55,
   marginBottom: 5,
   marginLeft: 10,
   alignItems: 'center',
   elevation: 8,
   backgroundColor: 'white'
   },
   image: {
   width: width / 2 - 20 - 10,
   height: width / 2 - 20 - 30,
   backgroundColor: 'transparent',
   position: 'absolute',
   top: -45
   },
   card: {
   marginBottom: 10,
   height: width / 2 - 20 - 90,
   backgroundColor: 'transparent',
   width: width / 2 - 20 - 10
   },
   title: {
   fontWeight: "bold",
   fontSize: 14,
   textAlign: 'center'
   },
   price: {
   fontSize: 20,
   color: 'orange',
   marginTop: 10
   },
   });
2. This is the JSON file
   [{
   "_id": {
   "$oid": "5f15d8852a025143f9593a7c"
   },
   "image": "",
   "brand": "PS3",
   "price": 250,
   "rating": 1,
   "numReviews": 0,
   "isFeatured": true,
   "name": "FIFA 20",
   "description": "The most hard FIFA ever",
   "category": {
   "$oid": "5f15d5cdcb4a6642bddc0fe9"
   },
   "countInStock": 25,
   "__v": 0
   },{
   "_id": {
   "$oid": "5f15d92ee520d44421ed8e9b"
   },
   "image": "",
   "brand": "IKEA",
   "price": 350.9,
   "rating": 5,
   "numReviews": 0,
   "isFeatured": true,
   "name": "Garden Chair",
   "description": "beautiful chair for garden",
   "category": {
   "$oid": "5f15d5b7cb4a6642bddc0fe8"
   },
   "countInStock": 10,
   "__v": 0
   },{
   "_id": {
   "$oid": "5f15d964e520d44421ed8e9c"
   },
   "image": "",
   "brand": "OBI",
   "price": 1350.9,
   "rating": 5,
   "numReviews": 0,
   "isFeatured": true,
   "name": "Swimming Pool",
   "description": "beautiful Swimming Pool for garden",
   "category": {
   "$oid": "5f15d5b7cb4a6642bddc0fe8"
   },
   "countInStock": 10,
   "__v": 0
   },{
   "_id": {
   "$oid": "5f15d9b3e520d44421ed8e9d"
   },
   "image": "",
   "brand": "OBI",
   "price": 490.9,
   "rating": 5,
   "numReviews": 0,
   "isFeatured": true,
   "name": "Grass Cut Machine",
   "description": "Grass Cut Machine for garden",
   "category": {
   "$oid": "5f15d5b7cb4a6642bddc0fe8"
   },
   "countInStock": 5,
   "__v": 0
   },{
   "_id": {
   "$oid": "5f15da13e520d44421ed8e9e"
   },
   "image": "",
   "brand": "Mobilix",
   "price": 1000,
   "rating": 5,
   "numReviews": null,
   "isFeatured": true,
   "name": "Sofa",
   "description": "Big Sofa for living room",
   "category": {
   "$oid": "5f15d5b2cb4a6642bddc0fe7"
   },
   "countInStock": 2,
   "__v": 0
   }]

And here is iterate part

```
const ProductContainer = () => {

    const [products, setProducts ] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setProducts(data);

        return () => {
            setProducts([])
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>Product Container</Text>
            <View style={{ marginTop: 100}}>
                <FlatList
                   horizontal
                    data={products}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <ProductList 
                    key={item.id}
                    item={item}
                    />}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.name}
                />
            </View>

        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to ask a question in stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

**This JSON data:**

```
[
   {
      "_id":{
         "$ oid":"123"
      },
      "image":"",
      "brand":"PS3",
      "price":250,
      "rating":1,
      "numReviews ":0,
      "isFeatured ":true,
      "name ":" FIFA 20 ",
      "description ":" Самая сложная FIFA за всю историю ",
      "category ":{
         " $ oid ":" 5f15d5cdcb4a6642bddc0fe9 "
      },
      " countInStock ":25,
      "__v":0
   }
]
```

**In the FlatList render item, you can immediately specify the fields.**

```
  **And the component will look like this**

const ProductCard = ({name, price, image, countInStock}) => (
  ....
);


<FlatList
      horizontal
      data={products}
      renderItem={({ item }) =>
     <ProductList 
      name={item.name} 
      price={item.price}
      image={item.image} 
      countInStock={item.countInStock}/> }
      keyExtractor={({_id) => _id} />
```